# Issue with ag-grid hide

Tags: ag-grid

I'm displaying columns in ag-grid depending on the response from back-end. I have total of 15 columns which I have hidden using 'hide'. Now depending on the response I'm using 'setColumnVisible' and displaying 4 - 9 columns per response.
However, the the columns are aligned towards the left and half of the grid is empty when doing this. 
Any help or work-around? 
Attaching screnshot of how the grid looks: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJJe9.png)

Answer (score 1):

Once you are done with showing/hiding the columns, you can call `sizeColumnsToFit` method of `gridApi` to achieve this.

```
sizeToFit() {
  this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
}
```

Check this link for reference: [Resizing Example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-resizing/#resizing-example)